# Does has_one association also causes an N+1 problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I often see the example below as an of N+1 problem.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

# N+1 problem
users.each do |user|
  user.posts.size
end
```

But is this also considered as N+1? It is not being considered by the [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet). But it queried the DB twice.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :post
end
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

# is an N+1 problem?
user = User.first
puts user.post.id
```

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

Any unloaded association can cause a N+1 query. It doesn't matter what assocation macro you are using (has_one, belongs_to, has_many, habtm). As long as you're calling an unloaded assocation it creates an additional database query.

```
irb(main):006:0> User.limit(5).each { |user| user.post }
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 5]]
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

As you can see this creates a textbook N+1 query issue which can be fixed by eager loading / including the assocation.

A `has_one` association is actually pretty much the same as `has_many` but with a LIMIT 1 tacked onto the query. It also generates the same methods as `belongs_to`. There is no difference when it comes to N+1 query issues.

Your second example is also a N+1 query. The only difference is that it will be less likely to be a problem since *n* is 1.

```
user = User.first     # SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1 
puts user.post.id     # SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

Comment: I'm not sure why Bullit wouldn't flag this. Sounds like a configuration issue.

Comment: thanks @max! N=1, but still an N+1 query.

Answer (score -2):

*An n+1 query occurs when we are loading a collection of records from a database, and also one related record for each record in that collection.*

Thus one to one association should not be considered as n+1 query.

Comment: This is completly false. If you have a collection of records and you iterate across it and call an unloaded assocation it will cause a N+1 query no matter what assocation macro you are using.